# VS Code missing global Tasks menu

Tags: visual-studio-code

The current VS Code documentation on integrating with external tools via tasks ([Integrate with External Tools via Tasks](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks)) refers to the "global Tasks menu", but my latest version 1.27.1 of VS Code has no Tasks menu. In my UI, the Terminal menu has the build tasks under it.  Have I done something to change my UI from standard?  Is the VS Code documentation out of date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's [just been renamed](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_27#_new-terminal-menu) to "Terminal":

> August 2018 (version 1.27)
>
> […]
>
> The **Tasks** menu was renamed to **Terminal** and some more entries for the Integrated Terminal were added.

Comment: gotcha! who would expect to run a task from the "terminal" menu...